# Java 8 compare objects from the same list(array index out of bound)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a hashmap with key,value as  `Map<String,List<Trade>>`. In the value object i.e. `List<Trade>` I have to compare each object. If any two of the object's property name "TradeType" is same then I have to remove those two from the list. I am trying to achieve as below. But I am getting "Array index out of bound exception" Also is there any better way to compare the same object inside list using streams??

```
Map<String,List<Trade>> tradeMap = new HashMap<>();
// Insert some data here
tradeMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .forEach(tradeList -> {
             List<Trade> tl = tradeList.getValue();
             String et = "";
         // Is there a better way to refactor this? 
             for(int i = 0;i <= tl.size();i++){
                   if(i == 0) {
                       et = tl.get(0).getTradeType();
                   }
                   else {
                       if(et.equals(tl.get(i).getTradeType())){
                           tl.remove(i);
                       }
                   }
              }
        });
```

Comment: Your index out of bounds error comes from here: `i <= tl.size()`  ... you want `<`, not `<=`

Answer (score 2):

Your description is not completely in sync with what your code does so I will provide a couple of solutions in which you can choose the one you're after.

First and foremost as for the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` you can solve it by changing the loop condition from `i <= tl.size()` to `i < tl.size()`. This is because the last item in a list is at index  `tl.size() - 1` as lists are `0` based.

To improve upon your current attempt you can do it as follows:

```
tradeMap.values()
        .stream()
        .filter(list -> list.size() > 1)
        .forEach(T::accept);
```

where `accept` is defined as:

```
private static void accept(List<Trade> list) {
      String et = list.get(0).getTradeType();
      list.subList(1, list.size()).removeIf(e -> e.getTradeType().equals(et));
}
```

and `T` should be substituted with the class containing the `accept` method.

The above code snippet only removes objects after the first element that are equal to the first element by trade type, which is what your example snippet is attempting to do. if however, you want distinct of all objects then one option would be to override `equals` and `hashcode` in the `Trade` class as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
     if (this == o) return true;
     if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
     Trade trade = (Trade) o;
     return Objects.equals(tradeType, trade.tradeType);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(tradeType);
}
```

Then the `accept` method needs to be modified to become:

```
private static void accept(List<Trade> list) {
        List<Trade> distinct = list.stream()
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        list.clear(); // clear list
        list.addAll(distinct);  // repopulate with distinct objects by tradeType
}
```

or if you don't want to override equals and hashcode at all then you can use the `toMap` collector to get the distinct objects:

```
private static void accept(List<Trade> list) {
        Collection<Trade> distinct = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Trade::getTradeType,
                        Function.identity(), (l, r) -> l, LinkedHashMap::new))
                .values();

        list.clear(); // clear list
        list.addAll(distinct);  // repopulate with distinct objects by tradeType    
}
```

if however, when you say:

> "If any two of the object's property name "TradeType" is same then I
>   have to remove those two from the list."

you actually want to remove all equal `Trade` objects by `tradeType` that have 2 or more occurrences then modify the `accept` method to be as follows:

```
private static void accept(List<Trade> list) {
       list.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Trade::getTradeType))
           .values()
           .stream()
           .filter(l -> l.size() > 1)
           .map(l -> l.get(0))
           .forEach(t -> list.removeIf(trade -> trade.getTradeType().equals(t.getTradeType())));
}
```

Comment: converting the `List` to intermediate data structure (`LinkedHashMap`) just to remove duplicates and getting back the refined `List` from it. Is it the best option? As I have your attention here, can you please comment on my answer below. I'm an admirer of your SO answers ( especially java-8). :)

Comment: The best option of the solutions provided is using the `equals` and `hashcode` approach for me. but as mentioned "if you don't want to override equals and hashcode" for whatever reason that is then using the `toMap` approach is _another option_ .

Comment: @mark42inbound Thank you, I appreciate your kind words. when you say "can you please comment on my answer below." , regarding what exactly?

Comment: Thanks for replying! But defining the equality of an instance of a domain class based on the value of one of its properties might not be the criterion for its absolute equality. I mean what if the condition for equality of two list objects mentioned by OP is custom for this use case. The criterion for the actual equality might have different implementation altogether.

Comment: By my previous comment, I wanted an expert's view (as I had your attention here) about about my answer(to this question) ;) I have started to learn Java 8 recently and am answering questions on SO as a practice.

Comment: Well, your questions are not really java-8 sepcific :) . Anyhow, this goes back to my previous comment "_if you don't want to override equals and hashcode for whatever reason that is then using the `toMap` approach is another option._" and this reason might be what you've just mentioned i.e.  "_But defining the equality of an instance of a domain class based on the value of one of its properties might not be the criterion for its absolute equality._" and "what if the condition for equality of two list objects mentioned by OP is custom for this use case".

Comment: when I said, "The best option of the solutions provided is using the `equals` and hashcode approach for me.". I was more referring to the fact that this now enables us to write more readable code in the `accept` method and avoids some intermediate creation of a map with the `toMap` collector, but if you really want to go into the details of how an `equals` method should be written then I can suggest [this very old but very helpful post](https://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html). whatever outcome you come with after reading I am pretty sure one of my two solutions will suffice.

Comment: I wanted some comments for [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51464487/8603014). Maybe somehow I can make it better...

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String,List<Trade>> tradeMap = new HashMap<>();
tradeMap.put("1",Arrays.asList(new Trade("A"),new Trade("B"),new Trade("A")));
tradeMap.put("2",Arrays.asList(new Trade("C"),new Trade("C"),new Trade("D")));

Map<String,Collection<Trade>> tradeMapNew = tradeMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                        e -> e.getValue().stream()                         //This is to remove the duplicates from the list.
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Trade::getTradeType,
                                        t->t,
                                        (t1,t2) -> t1,
                                        LinkedHashMap::new))
                            .values()));
```

Output:

```
{1=[A, B], 2=[C, D]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void test(){
    Map<String, List<Trade>> data = new HashMap<>();
    List<Trade> list1 = Arrays.asList(new Trade("1"), new Trade("2"), new Trade("1"), new Trade("3"), new Trade("3"), new Trade("4"));
    List<Trade> list2 = Arrays.asList(new Trade("1"), new Trade("2"), new Trade("2"), new Trade("3"), new Trade("3"), new Trade("4"));

    data.put("a", list1);
    data.put("b", list2);

    Map<String, List<Trade>> resultMap = data.entrySet()
                                             .stream()
                                             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, this::filterDuplicateListObjects));

    resultMap.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + value));
    // Don't forget to override the toString() method of Trade class.
}

public List<Trade> filterDuplicateListObjects(Entry<String, List<Trade>> entry){
    return entry.getValue()
                .stream()
                .filter(trade -> isDuplicate(trade, entry.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public boolean isDuplicate(Trade trade, List<Trade> tradeList){
    return tradeList.stream()
            .filter(t -> !t.equals(trade))
            .noneMatch(t -> t.getTradeType().equals(trade.getTradeType()));
}
```

Comment: Just noticed your code performs different logic to the other answers but I can completely understand it as the OP mentioned "If any **two of the object's property name "TradeType"** is same then I have to remove **those two from the list**.". This is actually why in the first paragraph of my answer it mentions to the OP "Your description is not completely in sync with what your code does....". Anyhow, I've also updated my answer to take that piece of info into consideration. as an aside there are improvements you can make with your code but it's minor so we can let that pass :).

Comment: @Aominè, I just saw your last edit. That's some really good _streaming_ ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, List<Trade>> tradeMap = new HashMap<>();

tradeMap.values()
    .stream()
    .forEach(trades -> trades.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Trade::getType))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .filter(tradesByType -> tradesByType.size() > 1)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .forEach(trades::remove));
```